How to create a nested dict in python
I would like to create a dict like below
newdict ={"MGH":{
            "A": {
                "B": {
                    "C":"abc"
                }
            }
}
}

My code is like this
import collections

newdict = collections.defaultdict(dict)
newdict["MGH"]["A"]["B"]["C"]= "abc"
print(newdict)

I got error saying
newdict["MGH"]["A"]["B"]["C"]= "abc"
KeyError: 'A'
Looks like the defaultdict only can have one level deep.
Is there a way to create a new dict from scrach?

You'd need to use something like def ddict(): return collections.defaultdict(ddict), and then newdict = ddict().
